# Linking gnu libraries c++ and fortran

Tags: gcc, fortran, g++, gfortran

I have spent the day searching for an answer to what should be a simple problem. I am building a c++ program to call a fairly large amount of existing fortran.  I started by changing the fortran main to a subroutine and then called it with a simple c++ main. My steps look like:

```
gfortran -c f1.f90 f2.f90 ......
g++ -c mn.cpp
gfortran -lstdc++ -o prog.exe mn.o f1.o ....
```

mn.cpp started out looking like the code below, and the above steps do work ok. I get a host of linker errors if I try to link with:

```
g++ -lgfortran (this never works!)
```

Next, I tried to instantiate a simple array class (remove the 2 commented lines). This produced linker errors concerning gxx_personality_seh0, vtable, and operator new.I get similar errors if I just create an array of doubles with new (remove comment), and if I remove the call to the fortran program completely (still linking with gfortran). Obviously, -lstdc++ does not bring in all the libraries needed. Which libraries are needed and how can I get it to link them?

I am using Windows 7 with Cygwin. The libraries it links are in ...lib/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3. I can post the linker output if it would be helpful.

mn.cpp which works (code commented out) is below:

```
  #include <string.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  //#include "array.h"
  extern "C" {
     void mnf90_(const char*,int);
  }
  int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  //   Array2D A;     // first derivative
     static const char *feos = "d/fld9x.dat";
     int npoint = 20;
  //   double *xc = new double[npoint];
     mnf90_(feos,strlen(feos));
  }
```

Comment: I think you have better chance to succeed with `g++` linker. Please post the linker output in both cases at any rate: it may give ideas.

Comment: The command line references to libraries (`-lxxx`) should follow the object code that references symbols inside those libraries.

Comment: Thanks IanH, that was the only problem. Putting the library option at the end, i.e. using g++ .............. -lgfortran works fine.  Options usually apply to the entire command, so I've not run into this before.

Comment: Use gcc to do the linking with -lgfortran -lstdc++.